# How can my bot notice if a user closes the chat?

Tags: c#, botframework

How can my bot be notified when a user closes a chat window, or leaves a chat in some way? I understand that there is an `Activity.MembersRemoved` property but that is only for members being removed from teams, not from an actual conversation between 1 bot and 1 user.

Comment: Looks like there is an `endOfConversation` event for that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-activities?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#endofconversation

Comment: That event is an event that has to be invoked, not one that will fire automatically when a user closes the chat. I also noticed that the bot won't throw an exception when it attempts to send a message to a conversation that is closed already. Is there any way to 'notice' that there is no participant on the other side?

Comment: What channel are you using for your bot?

Comment: I'm mostly using the WebChat channel I think.

Comment: For Webchat, use a backchannel event thrown by some javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Nicolas indicated, you can use the backchannel mechanism to throw if `activity.type === "event"`, which JavaScript listens for (and the browser / web chat ignores) to indicate when the user leaves the conversation using Activity.MembersRemoved. For more information, you can look at [this doc about backchannel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-backchannel?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) and [this backchannel bot sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/samples/backchannel/index.html). Hope that helps!